# Possibile sources of 5us-20us latency gap when sending long block of of serial data to tty device?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, serial-port

I have a trivial C program that just sends a large block of data out the serial port at a fast baud rate. When looking at the bits actually coming out of the port, I see that there is a almost always a gap in the serial bytes that comes near the beginning of the block (between 6ms and 20ms in) and lasts about the width of a couple of bytes (5us - 20us).

Here is a picture...

[image: Scope view of data gap]

The gap only comes at most 1 time per transmission, and once it happens the rest of the 100ms long transmission goes uninterrupted. The gaps happen about 9 out of 10 times I send a block.

The gap always occurs between bytes, so would not show up on a receiving computer as corrupted bytes and would not be a problem for normal serial communication (except that you are loosing a tiny amount of throughput), but it is important in my application because I want to use the serial port in a non-conventional application where the signal needs to be continuous.

At first I though it might be a scheduling issue, but nice-ing the process does not seem to have any effect on the gap. There are no other ready processes running on the machine.

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ ps all
F   UID   PID  PPID PRI  NI    VSZ   RSS WCHAN  STAT TTY        TIME COMMAND
4     0  2101     1  20   0   3744   804 n_tty_ Ss+  tty1       0:00 /sbin/getty
4     0  2102     1  20   0   3744   804 n_tty_ Ss+  tty2       0:00 /sbin/getty
4     0  2103     1  20   0   3744   804 n_tty_ Ss+  tty3       0:00 /sbin/getty
4     0  2104     1  20   0   3744   804 n_tty_ Ss+  tty4       0:00 /sbin/getty
4     0  2105     1  20   0   3744   804 n_tty_ Ss+  tty5       0:00 /sbin/getty
4     0  2106     1  20   0   3744   804 n_tty_ Ss+  tty6       0:00 /sbin/getty
0  1000 16370 27290  20   0   4136   956 -      R+   pts/1      0:00 ps all
0  1000 27290 27289  20   0   8252  5508 wait   Ss   pts/1      1:04 -bash
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ ./sendzeros /dev/ttyAMA0
Please start with ./sendzeros /dev/ttyS1 (for example)
```

I am trying to track down where this gap comes from in the hopes of eliminating it. Any ideas as to what might be the cause?

Next step will be to write an interrupt triggered device driver that directly keeps the UART's buffers full, but I'd prefer to stay in userland if that is at all possible. I'd also just like to know at this point even just so I can better understand where sources of latency like this can come from in the kernel.

The machine is a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian (wheezy).

Here is the code in case it might be relevant...

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <termios.h>


#define COUNT 24000             // Number of bytes to send...

int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
        struct termios tio;
        int tty_fd;

        printf("Please start with %s /dev/ttyS1 (for example)\n",argv[0]);

        tty_fd=open(argv[1], O_WRONLY );

        tcgetattr(tty_fd,&tio);

        tio.c_iflag=0;
        tio.c_oflag=0;
        tio.c_cflag=CS8|CREAD|CLOCAL;           // 8n1, see termios.h for more $
        tio.c_lflag=0;

        cfmakeraw( &tio );

        int ssr = cfsetospeed(&tio,  B2500000 );

        tcsetattr(tty_fd,TCSANOW,&tio);

        // This bit pattern makes it possible to see disruptions on an attached$

        char buffer[ COUNT ];

        memset( buffer , 0 , sizeof(buffer ) );

        write(tty_fd,&buffer,sizeof(buffer));                     // if new dat$

        close(tty_fd);

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```